# Compute row average in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
       Y1961      Y1962      Y1963      Y1964      Y1965  Region
0  82.567307  83.104757  83.183700  83.030338  82.831958  US
1   2.699372   2.610110   2.587919   2.696451   2.846247  US
2  14.131355  13.690028  13.599516  13.649176  13.649046  US
3   0.048589   0.046982   0.046583   0.046225   0.051750  US
4   0.553377   0.548123   0.582282   0.577811   0.620999  US
```

In the above dataframe, I would like to get average of each row. currently, I am doing this:

```
df.mean(axis=0)
```

However, this does away with the Region column as well. how can I compute mean and also retain Region column

Comment: Hi, could you post the actual and what you expect?

Comment: I totally understand how one might think 0 would mean rows and 1 would mean column-wise mean.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can specify a new column. You also need to compute the mean along the rows, so use `axis=1`.

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
>>> df
       Y1961      Y1962      Y1963      Y1964      Y1965 Region       mean
0  82.567307  83.104757  83.183700  83.030338  82.831958     US  82.943612
1   2.699372   2.610110   2.587919   2.696451   2.846247     US   2.688020
2  14.131355  13.690028  13.599516  13.649176  13.649046     US  13.743824
3   0.048589   0.046982   0.046583   0.046225   0.051750     US   0.048026
4   0.553377   0.548123   0.582282   0.577811   0.620999     US   0.576518
```

Comment: thanks @Alexander, this works! I do get a warning message: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead. How can I avoid that?

Comment: This should get rid of the warning: `df = df.assign(mean=df.mean(axis=1))`

Answer (score 27):

We can find the the mean of a row using the range function, i.e in your case, from the Y1961 column to the Y1965

```
df['mean'] = df.iloc[:, 0:4].mean(axis=1)
```

And if you want to select individual columns

```
df['mean'] = df.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4].mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Taking the mean based on the column names

I am just sharing this which might be useful for those folks who want to take average of a few columns based on the their names, instead of counting the column index. This simply would be done using pandas's `loc` instead of `iloc`. For instance, taking the odd-year average would be:

```
df["mean_odd_year"] = df.loc[:, ["Y1961","Y1963","Y1965"]].mean(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
df.drop('Region', axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.mean(), axis=1)
```

Comment: I like this solution. Although it is more complicated than the accepted answer, it gives you an idea of how to use the apply function to extract similar statistics by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to average column wise. Try this,

```
df.drop('Region', axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.mean())

# it drops the Region column
df.drop('Region', axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: I like this answer, but the question asked to average row-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to select the individual columns and get the average is:

```
df["row_average"] = df[[" Y1961","Y1962","Y1963"]].mean(axis=1)
print(df)
```