# finding mean across rows in a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe

```
L1_1 L1_2 L3_1 L2_1 L2_2 L1_3 L2_3 L3_2  ....
  3        5       1       5       7          2    3          2
  4        2      4        1        4         1    4          2
```

I need to find the mean all  "L1" , then  all "L2" , and then all  "L3 "

I tried

```
data["Mean"]=data.mean(axis=1)
```

that give me the sum across all "L1, L2 and L3" together

I also tried

```
data[['L1_1','L1_2','L1_3','Mean']].head()
```

but I have L1_1 to L1_20

so a loop sounds good. However, I cannot get a loop to work.

```
 for i in range(1,21):
     c = "'L1_" + i + "'," + c
```

Is a loop a good way to go here? or Is there a better?
If a loop is the way to go,  How do you get a loop to work in a data frame?

Comment: This post has your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750326/compute-row-average-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns `(axis=1)` with custom function of splitted values:

```
df1 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).mean()
#another solution 
#df1 = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).mean()
print (df1)
         L1   L2   L3
0  3.333333  5.0  1.5
1  2.333333  3.0  3.0
```

If want add nex columns to original `df` add [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) if want also rename columns names:

```
df = df.join(df1.add_suffix('_mean'))
print (df)
   L1_1  L1_2  L3_1  L2_1  L2_2  L1_3  L2_3  L3_2   L1_mean  L2_mean  L3_mean
0     3     5     1     5     7     2     3     2  3.333333      5.0      1.5
1     4     2     4     1     4     1     4     2  2.333333      3.0      3.0
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.