# getting an average of every row in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

I have a data frame like that. I am trying to get an average of every row in another column. I have tried:
`fesresults['avg_scores'] = np.mean(fesresults.scores)`, 
`fesresults['avg_scores'] = fesresults['scores'].mean(axis=1)` 
and all returning me `NaN` :/ Any help please?

edit: I think that my "scores" are string not int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute row average in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750326/compute-row-average-in-pandas)

Comment: but I think it's a possibility that my scores are string...

Comment: it looks like your scores are in a list in a single column. You should reshape your data so that each column has a single score (i.e., a tidy dataset). You will then have a much easier time using pandas built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to convert this to numeric:
`df['scores'] = df['scores'].apply(pd.to_numeric)`
and then
`df['avg_scores'] = np.mean(df['scores'])`

Thank you for your "help"