# Create a new column in pandas with average of other columns' data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently got some stock data for NYSE: MDLZ. There were columns of data for Open, Close, High, and Low. For people who know about stocks, the OHLC average is very important to identify if a stock is doing well. To add this column, I need to get the average of the other four columns for each row, and then implement that column.

Thanks for the help!

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\SVISHWANATH\Downloads\datasets\MDLZ_data.csv")
df
```

The image of how the dataframe looks is right here:
[image]

Comment: It would help if you paste the actual data not as an image

Comment: I can't paste the data, I can only paste the code

Comment: Why not? Copy that dataframe output in the question.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Compute row average in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750326/compute-row-average-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
df['OHLC Average'] = (df.open + df.high + df.low + df.close) / 4
```