# Average of rows with ranges in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For the following dataframe

```
              AA         BB        CC        DD
0   4.456648e+02  36.120182  1.707122  0.332993
1   3.974615e+02   8.733798  0.346957  0.332993
2   4.750258e+00   5.197949  0.365944  0.332993
```

I want to compute the average of rows with ranges as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64159301/859227). For example, I wrote:

```
df['mean1'] = df.iloc[:, 0:1].mean(axis=1)
df['mean2'] = df.iloc[:, 2:3].mean(axis=1)
```

So, `mean1` is averages for AA and BB and `mean2` is the average of CC and DD. But it isn't as you see below:

```
              AA         BB        CC        DD         mean1     mean2
0   4.456648e+02  36.120182  1.707122  0.332993  4.456648e+02  1.707122
1   3.974615e+02   8.733798  0.346957  0.332993  3.974615e+02  0.346957
2   4.750258e+00   5.197949  0.365944  0.332993  4.750258e+00  0.365944
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python slice `end` values are exclusive, not inclusive, so you are effectively taking the mean of `AA` and `CC`. You need to increase your `end` values by 1 to include `BB` and `DD` in each mean:

```py
df['mean1'] = df.iloc[:, 0:2].mean(axis=1)
df['mean2'] = df.iloc[:, 2:4].mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
           AA         BB        CC        DD       mean1     mean2
0  445.664800  36.120182  1.707122  0.332993  240.892491  1.020058
1  397.461500   8.733798  0.346957  0.332993  203.097649  0.339975
2    4.750258   5.197949  0.365944  0.332993    4.974104  0.349468
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, slices have the syntax `start:stop:step`, where the result goes from start (inclusive) up to (but not including) stop, increments of step. The third argument is 1 by default.

In your case, the row slice `0:1` includes only row 0. Similarly, `2:3` includes only row 2.