# Deleteing unwanted characters from .dat file then performing calculations on the result

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, split

I need to read a .dat file in Python. The file has 3 columns in total and hundreds of rows. The second and third column contain two characters followed by a float that I would like to extract--the second column always starts with `"SA"` and the third column always starts with `"SC"`. I am currently loading in the data and looping through each row to extract the values, but is there a better way to do it?

Once the data is cleaned, I want to perform some calculations on the result, namely computing the average.

Here is an example of two lines from the .dat file:

```
9:01:15 SA7.998  SC7.968 
9:01:16 SA7.998  SC7.968
```

Here is the code I am currently using.

```
import numpy as np
import os.path
from statistics import mean

time=[]
s_1=[]
s_2=[]
s1=[]
s2=[]
r1=[]
r2=[]
avgg=[]

# Reading data from file
with open('serial_2.dat','r') as f:
    dat=f.readlines()      
for i in dat: 
     y=i.split()                          # cleaning and getting columns without spaces  
     time.append(y[0])
     s1.append(y[1])
     s2.append(y[2])
#getting only numbers without strings (SA and SC)           
for counter in (range(0,len(s1))):
    S_1=s1[counter]
    r1.append(S_1[2:])
    r1_f=np.array(r1, dtype='float32')  

   S_2=s2[counter]
   r2.append(S_2[2:])
   r2_f=np.array(r2, dtype='float32')  
   avgg=r1_f+r2_f/2
print(np.mean(avgg))
```

Comment: You need to show us some of the lines from that file so we can understand your concerns.

Comment: @msci Please edit the question to include some of the data. The comments are not the right place to share important information; it should all be in the question itself.

Comment: @jared
I edited the question and added screenshot of example of the .dat file

Comment: @msci [Code and data should always be shared as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: `.dat` is a generic extension for data files, there's no standard format for it.

Comment: Also, be aware that your `np.mean(avgg)` will only be done to the last row since `avgg` is overwritten every loop.

Comment: What does "everytime.. I look here... seems only for strings" mean?

Comment: @jared
Thanks for your reply. 
I meant... when I try to remove specific character (letters) from each element in the list.. seems only working for strings not list.. 
I would appreciate if you could modify the code if you have any suggestion with comments.. to understand how to optimize it to make avgg for each row.. 

Thanks

Comment: As another aside, `avgg` should probably be `(r1_f+r2_f)/2` rather than what you have, which is `r1_f+r2_f/2`.

Comment: @msci You haven't really explained what prompted you to post this question. You seem to be reading in the data and extracting the numbers from the characters, so what is your issue? I've mentioned some issues above, but those were my own observations. You didn't mention what you are trying to fix.

Comment: I think you could use regex to make this a little simpler def extract_numbers(s):
    return [float(num) for num in re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', s)]. You dont need to delete the characters, you could just declare a variable which excludes those characters and use it in a calculation

Comment: @jared
I appreciate your feedback ... 
Actually, I would like to remove the character, in particular, letters in an easier and faster way from the beginning .. (as I believe.. I am adding lot of for loops..

Also... I would like to create a new column storing each average of column2 and column 3 

Hope is clear now!!

Comment: Is it always SA or SC pre-pended to the numbers? Or always exactly 2 letters? Or what else could it be?

Comment: @MarkSetchell always SA and SC... I mean for column 2 is SA and column3 is SC..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to do that:

```
#! pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('serial_2.dat', sep='\s+', header=None, names=['time', 's1', 's2'])
df['s1'] = df['s1'].str.extract('^[\D]+(.*)').astype(float)
df['s2'] = df['s2'].str.extract('^[\D]+(.*)').astype(float)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      time     s1     s2
0  9:01:15  7.998  7.968
1  9:01:16  7.998  7.968

>>> df.dtypes
time     object
s1      float64
s2      float64
dtype: object
```

If you have always 2 characters in s1 and s2 columns, you can avoid regex and strip the first two characters:

```
df['s1'] = df['s1'].str[2:].astype(float)
df['s2'] = df['s2'].str[2:].astype(float)
```

Then compute the global average:

```
# With pandas
>>> df[['s1', 's2']].mean().mean()
7.983

# With numpy
>>> np.mean(df[['s1', 's2']])
7.983
```

You can also compute the row average:

```
df['avg'] = df[['s1', 's2']].mean(axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
      time     s1     s2    avg
0  9:01:15  7.998  7.968  7.983
1  9:01:16  7.998  7.968  7.983
```

Comment: @Corralien
Thank you so much for your explanation.. Sounds more clean and faster... thats definitely helpful.. 
just last question if possible... would it be possible to create s3 include average for each row ??

Comment: @msci See [Compute row average in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33750531/12131013).

Comment: @Corralien
May I kindly ask to explain more what this part of the line:  
 extract('^[\D]+(.*)')  doing .. what is D+.* ?

Comment: For sure. `[\D]+` matches any character that's not a digit (equivalent to `[^0-9]+`) one or more times (`+`).

Answer (score 1):

You can strip or slice the prefix:

```
import csv

with open('serial_2.dat') as csv_file:
    dat = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')

    data =[]
    for row in dat:
        row = row[0], row[1].lstrip('SA'), row[2][2:]
        data.append(row)

    columns = ["time","SA","SC"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    
    df['SA']= df['SA'].astype(float)
    df['SC']= df['SC'].astype(float)
    df['avg'] = df[['SA', 'SC']].mean(axis=1)
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
      time     SA     SC    avg
0  9:01:15  7.998  7.968  7.983
1  9:01:16  7.998  7.968  7.983
time     object
SA      float64
SC      float64
avg     float64
dtype: object
```